# How can we get object index based on object property from a generic function? | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, abstraction

I've got a nicely setup set of generic functions for my database crud actions. I need a little more fine grained control for a few specialized functions. I want to be able to search through list of database objects by property. Seems impossible, with one caveat- the fact that all objects will have a property of uuid, which is what I want to search by. Sooo... it must be possible with some genius minds from SO.

Of course, I want to do something like this:

```
Future<int> getExampleIndexByUUID({required String uuid}) async 
  => await Hive.openBox<Example>('Example_Box')
     .then((box) => box.values.toList().indexWhere(example)
       => example.uuid == uuid);
```

But this above is not possible for generic types:

```
Future<T> getExampleIndexByUUID<T>({
  required T objectType,
  required String uuid,
  }) async => await Hive.openBox<T>(objectDatabaseNameGetter(objectType))
  .then((box) => box.values.toList().indexWhere(example)
    => example... );                    // Dead end- no property access here
```

PS I am aware that I can create methods outside the generic function to handle this. I can also create yet another large switch case to handle this, but this is what I want to avoid. I want to learn to abstract my code better in such a scenario. Any help or pointers appreciated! If my only option is to have a switch case or do the work outside the function, so be it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem (you don't explain why it's not possible or why the code is a "dead end"), but if you mean that you want to access different properties based on the generic type, pass a callback to your generic function to access the desired property.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I mean, because of the generic type I will not have property access (at the point where I have stated “dead code”). I will update my question to be more specific. How exactly would I structure that callback? I’m not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Define a common interface.**

  The best approach would be to make all of your classes that have a `uuid` property share a common base class, and then your generic function could restrict its type parameter to subtypes of that class:

  ```dart
  abstract class HasUuid {
    String get uuid;
  }

  class Example implements HasUuid {
    @override
    String uuid;

    Example(this.uuid);
  }

  Future<int> getExampleIndexByUUID<T extends HasUuid>({
    required T objectType,
    required String uuid,
  }) async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<T>(objectDatabaseNameGetter(objectType));
    return box.values.toList().indexWhere(
      (example) => example.uuid == uuid),
    );
  }
  ```
- **Use callbacks.**

  If you don't control the classes you want to use, you could have your generic function accept a callback instead to retrieve the desired property.  This would be more work for callers, but it also would be more flexible since callers can choose which property to access.

  ```dart
  Future<int> getExampleIndexByUUID<T>({
    required T objectType,
    required String Function(T) getUuid,
    required String uuid,
  }) async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<T>(objectDatabaseNameGetter(objectType));
    return box.values.toList().indexWhere(
      (example) => getUuid(example) == uuid),
    );
  }
  ```

  You could generalize that further:

  ```dart
  Future<int> getExampleIndex<T, PropertyType>({
    required T objectType,
    required PropertyType Function(T) getProperty,
    required PropertyType propertyValue,
  }) async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<T>(objectDatabaseNameGetter(objectType));
    return box.values.toList().indexWhere(
      (example) => getProperty(example) == propertyValue),
    );
  }
  ```
- **Use duck-typing.**

  If you can guarantee that all supplied types have a `uuid` member, another alternative would be to use `dynamic` and duck-typing (forgoing static type-safety):

  ```dart
  Future<int> getExampleIndexByUUID<T>({
    required T objectType,
    required String Function(T) getUuid,
    required String uuid,
  }) async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<T>(objectDatabaseNameGetter(objectType));
    return box.values.toList().indexWhere(
      (dynamic example) => example.uuid == uuid),
    );
  }
  ```

As an aside, it's bad style to mix `async`/`await` with `Future.then`.  Just use `async`/`await`.

Comment: Beautiful & informative answer. I like the first especially for future projects, however where I am now it would be too invasive to control my object classes so much. I'm going with the callback option. As for my style mixing async/await & Future.then, point taken. But, I have to admit that sometimes I get code kinky and I like "in-lining" shorter functions for my own eye-candy. Of course you can tell I don't work in a team ;p Anyway, thanks for the detailed & instructive answer